# Why am I getting an error trying to print a string in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf

To read a database file.  I'm trying to print the records as follows:

```
for record in race_db:
    print record
```

This gives me an error message

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 4: ordinal
>   not in range(128)

So I tried to map to unicode

```
string_record = [unicode(item) for item in record]
```

same thing. utf-8:

```
string_record = [unicode(item, "utf8") for item in record]
```

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.date found

I just want some to sort tostring functionality what am I doing wrong? I know I can successfully loop through all the records because something like:

```
print 'blah'
```

works fine.  It's just something in the encoding is tripping me up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single byte `\xC9` is not a valid encoding of anything in UTF-8.  You need to figure out how the text is currently encoding—in this case, it's most likely either [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) or [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  Then, decode it accordingly.

For example, if it's Windows-1252, you'd decode it as follows:

```
string_record = 'foo \xc9 bar'
print string_record.decode('Windows-1252')  # Output: "foo É bar"
```